# List of read only filesystems

Tags: filesystems, readonly, archive

What are all the read only filesystems still in use today?

I'm looking for one to create a read only archive flash drive.

The only ones I know about so far are:

- SquashFS
- ISO 9660

I'm looking for something that's fast and has a large per file size limit similar to exFAT. And supports long path/filename too.

EDIT 2

I'd like a read only filesystem that works on both Windows and Linux.

Also, I'm not asking for a comprehensive list, just a few options with pros and cons is good enough :)

Comment: Have you tried google or wikipedia?

Comment: Yeah but most of the results are about making a read only partition or disk drive writeable again

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some details. What will this drive be used for? What operating systems will it be mounted on? What kind of performance do you need? As it stands, this is just too broad and open ended.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems gives a couple more when I skimmed for read-only: AXFS and cramfs, but doesn't explicitly list ISO 9660 as readonly. That might be a start though

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you still haven't told us what operating systems you are targeting.

Comment: You are never going to get a comprehensive list, but the linux kernel is a good place to start... isofs, udf, cramfs, erofs, romfs, squashfs.

Comment: `tune2fs -O read-only /dev/whatever` would make your ext4 fs read-only. Not that one usually uses that on flash drives, but at least it should support whatever things you require. If you're on Linux that is. ISO 9660 is commonly used in read-only mode, but I'm not sure what its limitations actually are (and I know nothing of UDF or whatever). Though no filesystem will protect you from just wiping the raw device, you'd need write-protection on a lower level for that. E.g. the sliding tab on SD cards, and perhaps a bit of thin tape...